# Can I access a view element from an action without using a view model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Delete action something along this lines - abridged for this question:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var skill = _applicantSkillService.ReadApplicantSkill(id);
    try
    {
        _applicantSkillService.DeleteApplicantSkill(skill);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Now my main concern in setting an error message in the view without building the whole view model again. Is there any way I can do this?

My second concern I have just noticed is this action method requires a view return, and the view requires a non-null model. What 'escape routes' do I have here?

Comment: Can you use ajax instead of a get request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your error message in ViewData or TempData object and print it on view
like

```
@ViewData["err"].ToString()
```

Alternatively you can make a property of error message on your model and assign it before returning view like

```
model.Errormsg="your message";
```

Comment: Very good answer about the ViewData; I used typed models so much I'd totally forgotten about it!